# Difference between step,ramp and Impulse response

Tags: signal-analysis, impulse-response, control-systems

As, we can determine the response of the system by its 'impulse response' then why we use 'step response' and 'ramp response'. Is there any difference between all these response?

Comment: For an LTI system, you can derive any of those responses from the others, if that's what you're asking.  You must know the step height, ramp shape, etc.  For non-LTI systems, they might provide results that can't be derived from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the impulse response, the step and ramp responses describe an LTI-system. There are situations when the step response or the ramp response describe what we want to know about the system more directly than the impulse response. When the input to a system is a piece-wise constant function of time, the transitions are well described by the step response. It gives quite directly information about overshoot and settling time.

Comment: I think impulse response tells the transient response while step tells both the transient and steady-state response? but what about the ramp response? Where we need ramp response? for which situation ? any single example please?

Comment: Maybe a laser cutter that cuts sheets by straight lines. So the X and Y coordinates are intended to follow ramp segments, but won't do that exactly because of inertia.